How to Load multiple XML files into Azure SQL using Azure Data Factory
Load multiple XML files into Azure SQL using Azure Data Factory, with each XML file representing a table in the Azure SQL database. The ADF will copy the XML data and create tables on the fly in Azure SQL. However, I could not make it work. I don't know what I am missing.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.
storage:
address.xml, 
billing.xml,
registration.xml

transform XML files to Azure SQL tables and data:
dbo.address 
dbo.billing
dbo.registration

following steps setup

Get MetaData and Filter activities are getting all the xmls.
For each activity setting @activity('Filter').output.value



Copy data in the Foreach activity
source: wildcard file path/@item().name
sink: "connection": setting table @dataset().tablename
      "parameter": tablename
      "dataset properties":@replace(item().name,'.xml','')





There is a reason that the above approach is not working for xml files. The xml array stored inside a nested object and there should be mapping for this kind of data. But the multiple source xml files may have different schema so the mapping should be dynamic as per each source file.
Follow the below approach to achieve your requirement.
Your XML files should be of only level 1 nested for this approach, and you need to two pipelines as well.
First Get the child items and pass it to the For-Each activity in the parent pipeline. Create variables like below in the parent pipeline.

In the child pipeline, create the below parameters and variables.
{"source": {"path": "['to_replace']"},"sink": {"name": "to_replace"}}



In the parent pipeline, use lookup activity to get the xml data and by using this lookup output JSON, get the columns array of each array.
Then build the mapping JSON for each file. This is why the child pipeline will be used.
Use set variable activities to get the columns array.
Go through the below pipeline JSONs and use it as per your requirement.
Parent pipeline JSON:
{
    "name": "Parent",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Xml1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "XmlSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "wildcardFileName": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "XmlReadSettings",
                                        "validationMode": "none",
                                        "namespaces": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": true,
                                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "value": "@json(activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.res_map_string)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Xml1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "table_name": {
                                            "value": "@replace(item().name,'.xml','')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup1",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "XmlSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "wildcardFileName": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "XmlReadSettings",
                                        "validationMode": "none",
                                        "namespaces": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "Xml1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ref",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "ref",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@concat('\"$[''',replace(replace(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow),':')[0],'{',''),'\"',''),'''][''',replace(replace(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow),':')[1],'{',''),'\"',''),''']\"')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "get column names",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "ref",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "columns_arr",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@split(replace(split(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow),'[')[1],'}')[0],'{',''),',')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "get column names",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "child",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "columns_arr": {
                                        "value": "@variables('columns_arr')",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "collect_ref": {
                                        "value": "@variables('ref')",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "ref": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "columns_arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}

Child pipeline JSON:
{
    "name": "child",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.columns_arr",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "mapping",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(replace(variables('col_map'),'to_replace',replace(split(item(),':')[0],'\"','')))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "res map",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "res_map_string",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@concat('{\"type\": \"TabularTranslator\",\"mappings\":',string(variables('mapping')),',\"collectionReference\":',pipeline().parameters.collect_ref,'}')"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "columns_arr": {
                "type": "array"
            },
            "collect_ref": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "mapping": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "col_map": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "{\"source\": {\"path\": \"['to_replace']\"},\"sink\": {\"name\": \"to_replace\"}}"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}

The mapping will be provided dynamically to the copy activity like below.

The output tables will be generated automatically and also the data types will be preserved from source:

